# Swift - UIButton background colour does not change on click

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a bit of code to play a sound effect when my button is clicked on. This works fine, so I tried adding in a background color change when the button is clicked but it doesnt seem to work (even though it shows no errors). what am I doing wrong?

What I decalred them as:

```
var soundEffectWhats: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
var whatsup: UIButton = UIButton()
```

IBAction:

```
 @IBAction func whatsup(_ sender: Any) {
    soundEffectWhats.play()
    whatsup.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue}
```

Comment: That's because you have not even added whatsup to view yet?

Comment: But he write, that the click on the button works. So I think he have added whatsup to a view? @Cameron: Please share more code.

Comment: @ElTomato what do you mean?

Comment: Instead of whatsup.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue you can try: (sender as! UIButton).backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

Comment: Ahh yes, thank you sean! if you post as an answer i will gladly mark it as accepted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
(sender as! UIButton).backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

instead of

```
whatsup.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

to take care, that you get the right reference.

If you want to be carefully, you could use:

```
(sender as? UIButton)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

but take care, that backgroundColor will only be executed, if the cast was successfully.

UPDATE: 
As **Sulthan** has mentioned in the comments, you can declare the `sender` as `UIButton` directly:

```
@IBAction func whatsup(_ sender: UIButton) {
    soundEffectWhats.play()
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}
```

Comment: You should declare `sender` as `UIButton` in the first place.